# How to install org-mode from Org ELPA archives with emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have added Org ELPA archives to my .emacs file through the following elisp code:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Afterwards, when I M-x list-packages, I can see two "org" in the list, one is from gnu and the other is from org. However, when I evaluate the following code in emacs, it will not install org-mode from Org ELPA archives, plus, it tells me that org is installed.

```
(package-install 'org)
```

Is there a way to force emacs to download the latest org-mode from Org ELPA archives with emacs lisp?

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore inappropriate for SO. You could ask it on the Emacs SE site or better yet on the org-mode mailing list.

Comment: See this thread entitled "*Can't Install org Through Package Manager*":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/cant-install-org-through-package-manager .  There is a comment by Tyler that states:  "`package-install` only works for packages that aren't already installed. org mode is installed by default, so it will never show up for `package-install`. You can upgrade it to a newer version via `package-list-packages`. – Tyler Apr 26 at 14:38"

Comment: Thanks lawlist, your suggestion works!

Comment: No new Org versions will be released on Org ELPA after 9.5.
Instead newer version are hosted on the GNU ELPA archive.  
  
  
```(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)```